# how create a dynamic page in react typescript and json file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have made an app that has a users page and each user has its own page. this is my code in the app.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

import { NavLink,Link, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  Home,
  About,
  Contact,
  Courses,
  Blog,
  BlogDetail,
  CourseDetail,
} from "./pages";

import { LayoutProvider } from "./layout";

interface AppProps {}

const users = [
  {
    name: `Param`,
  },
  {
    name: `Vennila`,
  },
  {
    name: `Afrin`,
  },
];

const UsersPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {
        users.map((user, index) => (
          <h5 key={index}>
            <Link to={`/user/${index + 1}`}>{user.name}'s Page</Link>
          </h5>
        ))
      }
    </>
  );
};

const UserPage = ({ match, location }) => {
  const { params: { userId } } = match;

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <strong>User ID: </strong>
        {userId}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>User Name: </strong> 
        {users[userId - 1].name}
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <LayoutProvider>
        <div className="content">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/About" component={About} />
          <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/Courses" component={Courses} />
          <Route path="/Course-Detail" component={CourseDetail} />
          <Route path="/Blog" component={Blog} />
          <Route path="/Blog-Detail" component={BlogDetail} />

          <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
          <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersPage} />
          <Route exact path="/user/:userId" component={UserPage} />
        </div>
      </LayoutProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

but i get an error for this part:

```
const UserPage = ({ match, location }) => {
  const { params: { userId } } = match;

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <strong>User ID: </strong>
        {userId}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>User Name: </strong> 
        {users[userId - 1].name}
      </p>
    </>
  );
};
```

how do i convert this part to work? it gives me this error for using match and location:

- Binding element 'match' implicitly has an 'any' type
- Binding element 'location' implicitly has an 'any' type